# Remove The Space in a String in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, split

I want to know how to remove space in a string.
For Example take a string `a= "Hello World"`. Once the whitespace is found then `"Hello"` and `"World"` Should be Separated and get stored in separate Strings.
 Like `b="Hello"`   and  `c="World"`. It is possible to do. Can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to clarify in case it is unclear, the below examples of string.Split() are returning string arrays (`string[]`).

Comment: So, are you trying to remove spaces, or are you trying to parse out tokens delimited by spaces?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do a

```
  var words = a.Split(' ');
```

This will return an array with each word in one

```
foreach(var word in words)
{
   Trace.WriteLine(word);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Simply use in-build split functionality:

```
string a= "Hello World"
var words = a.Split(' ');
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx):

```
string[] words = "Hello World".Split(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

If performance is important, you can probably outperform `String.Split()` using code like this [here](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-text-parsing-helper-class).

Answer (score -3):

```
string cname = "Hong Kong";
cname = Regex.Replace(cname, @"\s", "-");



Response.Write(cname);
```